# Set width of native html5 date and time pickers on iOS devices

Tags: ios, html, css, mobile-safari

I'm using the native date and time pickers with type=date and type=time for the mobile version of a website I'm working on. The input fields are not respecting the css I have, though.

Desktop:

[image: Desktop]

iOS devices:
[image]

Essentially I need the two date and time inputs to fill ~50% of the width. This is the html and css I'm using:

```
<div class="arriveWrapper">
            <div class="arriveDateWrapper fieldWrapper">
                <input class="arriveDate" name="arriveDate" type="date" placeholder="What date?" />
            </div>
            <div class="arriveTimeWrapper fieldWrapper">
                <input class="arriveTime" name="arriveTime" type="time" placeholder="What time?" />
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>


.arriveDateWrapper {
    width: 49%;
    margin-right: 2%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

        .arriveDate {
            width: 100%;
            height: 28px;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

.arriveTimeWrapper {
    width: 49%;
    float: left;
}

    .arriveTime {
        width: 100%;
        height: 28px;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
```

If anyone can tell me how to get the placeholders to show up when using the native date/time pickers that would be great, as well.

Thanks!

Comment: post the rest of the structure

Comment: I've added more of the structure. Is there a way to set the width of these inputs?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Just add this to your styles

```
.arriveDate, .arriveTime  {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
}
```

The reason behind this is that IOS device render by default the inputs using the IOS buttons

Answer (score 12):

To avoid losing any style elements applied to other input boxes, use **textfield** instead of **none**.

```
.arriveDate, .arriveTime  {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```

Also, if you just want to make all the date fields appear like textboxes but still work like date fields...

```
input[type="date"]
{
    display:block;
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
    min-height: 1.2em;
}
```