# iOS safari messes up input type=date

Tags: html, ios, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using HTML 5's `<input type="date" />`. Works fine in different browsers, BUT there is always the one who messes everything up:

[image: See the date fields get shrinked on the required size]

The problem hereby is the size of the field: Using [Bootstrap v3.2](http://getbootstrap.com/) for the design, these inputs are in a form and have `class="form-control"` which should make them wider (as the text input above and the select below).

Is there a way to say iOS that the datepicker should be 100% wide? `style="width:100%"` does nothing. `width:1000px` works indeed, `width:100% !important` does nothing.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: can you post your code here??? this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15857092/set-width-of-native-html5-date-and-time-pickers-on-ios-devices

Comment: @ManjunathSiddappa using this solution, the field just looks like a text input with the functionality of a datepicker when you click it. It should actually look like a datepicker as it does now, but be a bit wider...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is the way iOS treats `input type="date"`. I wouldn't worry about native styling. It may look off, but people using iOS are used to it.

You can use `min-width:95%` on the date input. It makes it fit, at least in iOS 8, and doesn't change the appearance otherwise. Though I haven't tested in Android or earlier version of iOS. Alternatively, to just center it, you can add `.center-block` to the input, so at least it's center and doesn't look so off.

[image]

**DEMO: http://jsbin.com/civor/1/**

```
.input-min-width-95p {min-width:95%;}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="date" class="form-control input-min-width-95p" ...
```

Comment: If min-width solves the problem, you could also try a min-width of 100% with a box-sizing of border-box.

Comment: @ShaneS.Anderson box-sizing:border-box is the default for everything including :after, :before in Bootstrap. So: nope.

Comment: FWIW, and this may be super out of date, but the following hasn't proven true to me: "it may look off, but people using iOS are used to it". It looks awful and I get messages from people who are confused by it all the time because so few websites use the native picker style.

Answer (score 24):

This fixes all my date fields on IOS.

```
input[type="date"]
{
    display:block;
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
    min-height: 1.2em;
}
```

Comment: or `-webkit-appearance: none`.

Comment: Come 2021 this is still useful. I find that the display:block may not be needed but the min height and textfield elements definitely are.

Comment: `-webkit-appearance: textfield;` didn't work for me, but `-webkit-appearance: none;` did

Answer (score 4):

In my case I fixed it with the "new" [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes) layout type:

```
    input {
        display:flex;
        display:-webkit-flex;
        flex: 1 0 0;
        -webkit-flex: 1 0 0;
    }
```

DEMO: http://output.jsbin.com/bugeqowamu/1

NOTE: the container must also have `display: flex;` as in the demo.

Answer (score 3):

There are two solutions for this problem as shown in below code.

For this ios issue you can use any of the solution below.

Method 1)  Add c1 class css,it will increase width of control along . This it will change its UI and look like normal inputbox ie it won't show dropdown symbol (Refer  Method 1 OUTPUT )

Method 2)  Add c2 class css,it will just increase width of control without removing dropdown symbol
(Refer Method 2 OUTPUT )

**Method 1 OUTPUT**
[image]

**Method 2 OUTPUT**
[image]

```css
.c1{
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
}

.c2{
 min-width:95%;
}
```

```html
Method 1)
<input type="time" class="form-control c1" name="txtIn"
                                                id="txtIn" >






Method 2)                      
<input type="time" class="form-control c2" name="txtOut"
                                                id="txtOut" >
```

Comment: This is for type=time not type=date

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution for bootstrap 3 form-controls within input-groups with the basics from Razvan Grigore's answer.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="amount">Input Label</label>
  <div class="input-group">
  <div class="fixIosInputLayout">
    <input id="amount" type="time" class="form-control"/>
  </div>
  <span class="input-group-addon"> unit </span>
  </div>
</div>

/* fix for ios safari inputs width */
.fixIosInputLayout
{
  display: flex;
}
.fixIosInputLayout>input.form-control[type="date"], .fixIosInputLayout>input.form-control[type="time"]
{
  display:flex; 
  display:-webkit-flex; 
  flex: 1 0 0; 
  -webkit-flex: 1 0 0; 
  border-radius: 4px; 
}
.input-group>.fixIosInputLayout>input.form-control[type="date"], .input-group>.fixIosInputLayout>input.form-control[type="time"] 
{ 
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px; 
}
```

So makes the input full-width like other bootstrap inputs with class form-control and shows the input-group-addon (here on right side) correctly.

Preview: (it is on Chrome, on ios the value is centered.

[image: preview]

Answer (score -9):

Twitter bootstrap is mobile-first and will also works on all the modern browser...
You can use some responsive utilities... [like](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities)

Comment: Not sure how this addresses the question at all